# React Hook) useCallback vs Declaring a function outside a component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

if useCallback used to prevent what declare function every render,
how about declare function outside of component(case1) instead declare inside(case3)?

```
function case1() {
 /* do stuff */                        // declared at JS script loaded(not sure)
}

const App = () => {

  const case2 = () => {/* do stuff */};                   // declared every render
  const case3 = useCallback(() => {/* do stuff */}, []); // declared at first render

  return (<></>);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only pass some variables as parameters for the `case1` function outside of the component. See the below example:

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';

const Button = React.memo<{ onClick: any; children: any }>(({ onClick, children }) => {
  console.log('render child');
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{children}</button>;
});

const case1 = (dep) => {
  console.log('expensive work in case1, dep: ', dep);
};
export default function App({ dep }) {
  const case3 = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('expensive work in case3, dep: ', dep);
  }, [dep]);

  const case1Bound = case1.bind(this, dep);
  return (
    <div>
      {/* use function declared outside of a component */}
      {/* <Button onClick={() => case1(dep)}>click me</Button> */}
      <Button onClick={case1Bound}>click me</Button>
      {/* useCallback */}
      {/* <Button onClick={case3}>click me</Button> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Suppose the `case1` function depends on the `dep` props and is triggered by the click event of the `Button` component. You can only pass the `dep` as a parameter through the arrow function or the `.bind()` method. As a result, it creates a new function for the `onClick` prop every time the `App` component renders. It will cause the `React.memo()` shallow comparison return `false`,  the `Button` component will re-render. See below test:

```js
import 'jest';
import React from 'react';
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './index';

describe('useCallback-vs-function-outside-component', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const { rerender } = render(<App dep={1} />);
    const button = screen.getByText(/click me/);
    fireEvent.click(button);
    rerender(<App dep={1} />);
    fireEvent.click(button);
  });
});
```

Logs:

```sh
render child
expensive work in case1, dep:  1
render child
expensive work in case1, dep:  1
```

With `useCallback`:

> `useCallback` will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.

So the `dep` is NOT changed, the `case3` function is the function created for the first time, and `useCallback` will return directly from memory instead of creating a new one. The `Button` `onClick` prop is NOT changed, the shallow comparison of `React.memo()` will return `true`, so it will render only once.

Logs:

```sh
render child
expensive work in case3, dep:  1
expensive work in case3, dep:  1
```

Comment: But isn't the example of case1 making things complicated unnecessarily?
If I want the callback to handle the change in dependency, I would rather send dependency as a separate prop and callback as a separate prop.
The problem in your case above is the use of the inline function and not necessarily the outer function.

I could screw up the performance of even the `useCallback` by passing it as a callback function.